# Automatic alignment of representations if the keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I can not deal with autolayout, I need to implement similar to facebook / instagram login page. That is, when you click on the input field login or password, the keyboard and all representations adapt to the new size of the window.

[image]

After the appearance of the keyboard, it looks like this:
[image]

```
func updateBottomLayoutConstraintWithNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let animationDuration = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
    let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let convertedKeyboardEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardEndFrame, from: view.window)
    let rawAnimationCurve = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).uint32Value << 16
    let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions.init(rawValue: UInt(rawAnimationCurve))

    bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = (view.bounds).maxY - convertedKeyboardEndFrame.minY

    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0.0, options: animationCurve, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tips to Autolayout:

1. Use `scroll view` or `static table view`.
2. If you use static table view all scrolling and keyboard related stuffs handled by table view itself.
3. If you use scroll view just start to give constraints from top element to end and use [this](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) library it is very useful and easy to use. See below image

Thanks:)
[image]

Comment: A little something instagram run and see how it is implemented. By clicking on the input field all the elements are shifted upwards.